# scp a file to a unix server in node js

Tags: node.js, scp

I'm using the below code to copy a file to a remote unix server, but only the first line of the source file is written to the destination file.

```
var client = require('scp2');
var ssh = require('node-sshclient');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var waitOn = require('wait-on');

module.exports.copy =  function(filename, cb){

    client.scp(filename, 'root:hoplehd@10.20.138.185:22:/opt/', function(err) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);    
        }else{
            console.log("succeeded copying the file to remote server");
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...It copies the file in the destination with only first line in it.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have solved the problem. I came across similar problem yesterday and this is how i solved it. Hope this helps someone who might come across similar problem in future. I am a newbie to node JS, so pardon me for any mistakes.

```
var client = require('scp2');
client.scp(pldBinary, {
    host: '10.20.138.185',
    username: 'root',
    password: 'hoplehd',
    path: '/opt/'
}, function(err) {
   if(err){
      console.log('There has been some error!!!');
      console.log(err);
   }else{
      console.log('succeeded copying the file to remote server');   
   }
}
```